# Get a string and place it at the start of a line until the next string is found

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a big non-standard xhtml file that I'm using sed (about 4 times) to iterate down to just the basics I need to throw the data into a MySQL database. My last bit I'm struggling with. The file is formatted like:

```
 Tue Aug 18 2015
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,2,275
0,0,0,3,287
0,0,0,0,327
0,0,0,3,335
0,0,0,0,413
 Wed Aug 19 2015
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,2,275
0,0,0,3,287
0,0,0,2,308
 Thu Aug 20 2015
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,2,458
0,0,0,3,469
0,0,0,0,472
0,0,0,3,503
0,0,0,2,534
```

There is always a space before the day.
There can be any number of CSV value lines after the date.

What I'm hoping can be achieved is:

```
Tue Aug 18 2015,0,0,0,0,0
Tue Aug 18 2015,0,0,0,2,275
Tue Aug 18 2015,0,0,0,3,287
Tue Aug 18 2015,0,0,0,0,327
Tue Aug 18 2015,0,0,0,3,335
Tue Aug 18 2015,0,0,0,0,413
Wed Aug 19 2015,0,0,0,0,0
Wed Aug 19 2015,0,0,0,2,275
Wed Aug 19 2015,0,0,0,3,287
Wed Aug 19 2015,0,0,0,2,308
Thu Aug 20 2015,0,0,0,0,0
Thu Aug 20 2015,0,0,0,2,458
Thu Aug 20 2015,0,0,0,3,469
Thu Aug 20 2015,0,0,0,0,472
Thu Aug 20 2015,0,0,0,3,503
Thu Aug 20 2015,0,0,0,2,534
```

and if it's possible, to strip the day and throw in a few more commas for easier manipulation in a PHP script, like:

```
Aug,18,2015,0,0,0,0,0
Aug,18,2015,0,0,0,2,275
Aug,18,2015,0,0,0,3,287
Aug,18,2015,0,0,0,0,327
Aug,18,2015,0,0,0,3,335
Aug,18,2015,0,0,0,0,413
Aug,19,2015,0,0,0,0,0
Aug,19,2015,0,0,0,2,275
Aug,19,2015,0,0,0,3,287
Aug,19,2015,0,0,0,2,308
Aug,20,2015,0,0,0,0,0
Aug,20,2015,0,0,0,2,458
Aug,20,2015,0,0,0,3,469
Aug,20,2015,0,0,0,0,472
Aug,20,2015,0,0,0,3,503
Aug,20,2015,0,0,0,2,534
```

Is there a few commands that can be used?

Comment: Just to be clear, the day/date line never contains any comma whereas all other lines contain at least one comma ?

Comment: Yep. That's the way the files been edited down to. Thanks!

Comment: Also, if you're using `sed` 4 times already then something's not right... You should be able to do pretty much anything in 2 passes.

Comment: In addition to what @don_crissti said about 2 passes, the [xml2](http://ofb.net/~egnor/xml2/) package is a LOT less fussy about improperly formatted XML or XHTML than `xmlstarlet` (and easier to use too).  `xml2`'s purpose is to convert XML/HTML data into a line-oriented FLAT format suitable for use with tools like `awk`, `sed`, `grep`, etc.  It can also convert to/from CSV files.  Useful examples here: http://blog.mydream.com.hk/howto/linux/convert-xml-to-csv-using-xml2 (ignore the stuff about compiling it, it's probably already packaged for your distro)

Comment: This is a one-time batch process that I was running - I'll no doubt have to make something similar in the future where I'll hopefully use what I've learned here as a starter and get the amount of runs down! Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
sed '/,/!{                       # if there's no comma on this line
y/ /,/                           # translate spaces to commas
h                                # copy pattern space over the hold buffer
d                                # delete pattern space
}
//{                              # if the line contains commas
G                                # append hold space content to pattern space
s/\(.*\)\n,[^,]*,\(.*\)/\2,\1/   # swap lines removing newline, the day part and
}                                # first two commas and adding a comma after year
' infile
```

If you prefer a `gnu sed` one-liner:

```
sed -E '/,/!{y/ /,/;h;d};//{G;s/(.*)\n,[^,]*,(.*)/\2,\1/}' infile
```

It's similar with `awk`:
If the line contains no commas you could format the date via `sprintf`, save the result into a variable e.g. `dt` and then go to `next` record. Else just prepend `dt` to `$0` (that is the current line):

```
awk '!/,/{dt=sprintf("%s,%s,%s,", $2, $3, $4);next};$0=dt$0' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

```awk
awk -F, -v OFS=, '/^[[:blank:]]+/ {
                      str=gensub(/ /,",","g",$0);
                      sub(/^,+[^,]+,/,"",str);
                      next
                  };

                  !/^[[:blank:]]+/ {print str,$0}' nick.txt
```

(this can, of course, be all on one line.  I wrote and tested it as a one-liner, and then added line-feeds and indentation to make it more readable here)

For lines beginning with one or blank characters (i.e. spaces or tabs), this `awk` script, converts all  spaces to commas, saves the modified line in a variable called `str`, and then removes the initial comma(s) and all text up to and including the next comma.

For lines not beginning with blank character(s), it prints the line prefixed with the current value of `str`.

Warning: if there are any CSV data lines **before** the first date line, those lines will be printed with only a single comma as the prefix.

**Output:**

```
Aug,18,2015,0,0,0,0,0
Aug,18,2015,0,0,0,2,275
Aug,18,2015,0,0,0,3,287
Aug,18,2015,0,0,0,0,327
Aug,18,2015,0,0,0,3,335
Aug,18,2015,0,0,0,0,413
Aug,19,2015,0,0,0,0,0
Aug,19,2015,0,0,0,2,275
Aug,19,2015,0,0,0,3,287
Aug,19,2015,0,0,0,2,308
Aug,20,2015,0,0,0,0,0
Aug,20,2015,0,0,0,2,458
Aug,20,2015,0,0,0,3,469
Aug,20,2015,0,0,0,0,472
Aug,20,2015,0,0,0,3,503
Aug,20,2015,0,0,0,2,534
```

Comment: btw, why don't you just use a `date` field in your mysql database?  Then you wouldn't need to munge the date with extra commas.