# Timestamping each line of a file with a date taken from the file itself

Tags: awk

I have a file with the following repeating pattern:

```
date
line 1
line 2
...
line x
```

Example:

```
10/30/2016 12:10:00
xxx 123
yyy 456
zzz 789

10/30/2016 12:20:00
xxx 234
yyy 567
zzz 890
```

How can I timestamp each line with the corresponding date, i.e:

```
10/30/2016 12:10:00
10/30/2016 12:10:00 xxx 123
10/30/2016 12:10:00 yyy 456
10/30/2016 12:10:00 zzz 789
10/30/2016 12:20:00
10/30/2016 12:20:00 xxx 234
10/30/2016 12:20:00 yyy 567
10/30/2016 12:20:00 zzz 890
```

I think it should be possible with AWK, but I'm not very experienced with it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: See also [Get a string and place it at the start of a line until the next string is found](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/285523)

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to do it like:

```
awk '/^[[:digit:]/]+[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]:]+/ {d=$1 " " $2; print; next; } /[^[:space:]]/ { print d " " $0 }'
```

which will match any sequence of digits and `/` followed by some spaces then a series of digits and `:`s, which should match our date.  If we find one, we save the first two fields in a variable, `d`, then print this line and move on.  Then any time we find a line that has at least one non-space character (since you seem to be stripping the blank lines in your example) we print the current value in `d` then the current line.

Comment: Thank you, Eric. I don't actually need to stripe the blank lines. Your answer works great, anyway.